# Java returning incorrect \n character after decrypting from file

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bufferedoutputstream

I have this strange issue with java IO, in combination with AES encryption.
I am writing some encrypted text to a binary file, appending \n at the end of text. Say,
my beautiful string...
look! Another of my beautiful strings...

When I read the data back, I get the following text in return with a lot of extra tabs:
my beautiful string...
                        look! Another of my beautiful strings...

Here is my self-contained code:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class SecurityUtil
{
    public static final String  ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM    = "AES";
    public static final String  CHARACTER_SET           = "UTF-8";
    private static final int    BLOCKS                  = 128;
    private static final String KEY                     = "SomeSortOfEncryptionKey";

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String str = "my beautiful string...\n";
        byte[] encrypt = SecurityUtil.encrypt (str);
        File f = new File ("C:\\myfile.dat");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f, true));
        bos.write(encrypt);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

        str = "look! Another of my beautiful strings...";
        encrypt = SecurityUtil.encrypt (str);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f, true));
        bos.write(encrypt);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length ()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (f);
        fis.read (buffer);
        fis.close ();

        String decrypt = SecurityUtil.decrypt (buffer);
        System.out.println(decrypt);
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt (String text)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] rawKey = getRawKey (KEY.getBytes (CHARACTER_SET));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec (rawKey, ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance (ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            return cipher.doFinal (text.getBytes (CHARACTER_SET));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (BadPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt (byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] rawKey = getRawKey (KEY.getBytes (CHARACTER_SET));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec (rawKey, ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance (ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init (Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal (data);
            return new String (decrypted);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch (BadPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static byte[] getRawKey (byte[] seed)
    {
        try
        {
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance (ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance ("SHA1PRNG");
            sr.setSeed (seed);
            kgen.init (BLOCKS, sr);
            SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey ();
            byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded ();
            return raw;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the console output (with extra spaces):

```
my beautiful string...
                                                                     look! Another of my beautiful strings...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At the very least, you are ignoring the return value if the `InputStream.read()` method, so with the very high probability you are not reading the entire file.

Comment: I didn't get you. How am I not reading complete file? I get first character and last character printed, what's behaving odd is a character in the mid.

Comment: Ah, i see - you are also writing two separate blocks of encrypted data into the same file and later reading and decoding them as one single block.

Comment: Yup! The purpose is to append the data in the same file.
And can you please remove the down vote? This isn't a spam question for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I got it. You cannot just append the encrypted text to a file. One way of solving this is extracting existing text from the file, append the new text, encrypt and write in the file again.
This doesn't seem to be a good solution, but in my case, where there is little text in a file, this can work.